# How to avoid "Apk from unknown source" grant without google play?

Tags: google-play, apk, android-source, signature

I have an APK that I don't want to publish into Google Play.
Is it possibile to sign it with my certificate and do not require the user to tick "Install from unknow source" option?
How is defined "The known source"?

Comment: Known source is an app store e.g. Google Play, Samsung Galaxy Store

Comment: Does it depend on the phone manufacturer?